# How to set field type while performing $push in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to update a collection with code bellow

```
db.testPrice.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("60a36bd7ce662102d0959490") }, 
    { $push: { 
        'priceList': { 
            $each: [
                { 'item': ObjectId('60a194a5cea5a60b4f9fb1a3'), 'price': 1000 },
                { 'item': ObjectId('60a194a5cea5a60b4f9fb1aa'), 'price': 10001 }
            ]
        }
    }}
)
```

I want item to be stored as an ObjectId but I can't make it. I'm getting error "TypeError: Argument passed in must be a Buffer or string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"

thanks

Comment: convert it same as you did for _id in query part, `{'item': ObjectId('60a194a5cea5a60b4f9fb1a3'),`

Comment: I already tried this and then I'm getting this error message TypeError: Argument passed in must be a Buffer or string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Comment: edit your question and show how you are passing..

Comment: I have edited my question and posted outcome

Comment: your query looks good and also items id are correct see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pJg9N2nK_KN), where you are executing this query?

Comment: at mongodb compass shell

Comment: i don't see any issue, i also executed in mongo compass, its working perfectly..

Comment: I have copy your code from playground (which is the same as the one I was trying to execute before) and it worked :) Don't know what happened

Comment: that i copied from your question, probably you missed something, like incorrect name of `ObjectId` including case, incorrect item id..